# is it possible to give html or php code as variable value?

Tags: php, variables

I have a html code including with javascript / php code. 
I wanna use this for value of variable. 
like this:

```
function abc($content){
     $content='my html code ';
     //  rest of code
}
```

It will output as a txt file.

But for that reason my script will be so bigger.Is there any way to submit that html code to any site and put a link in variable to grab the script from that source ?

Comment: Why do you override the contents of the parameter with a constant string? What's the use of the parameter here, anyway, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all HTML code into a separate file and load it using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
function abc($content){
     $content= file_get_contents( 'myHTMLcode.htm' );
     //  rest of code
}
```

Comment: +1 for this option. It sure will clean up code and separate it. You might need a ton of files though..

Comment: Thanks . I think it will easier for me. 
And can you tell me that where can i put my html file to grab ? I mean same folder of main scrip ?

Comment: @user1687804 You can put the file in any folder, the PHP script has access to. In some cases it might be best to put it somewhere outside the web root.

Comment: @Sirko , if i wanna put that htm file to another sites, then what will be that code ?

Comment: @user1687804 What do you mean by "put to another site"? If you just want to reference it on another site on the same machine, just change the path accordingly.

Comment: @Sirko , Sorry typing mistake !
Actually  if i wanna put that html in another site. And then grab the code from it, then what code i need to use ?

Comment: @user1687804 Sorry, but I still don't get, what you want to do. You can use `file_get_contents()` anywhere and as much as you like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17811/discussion-between-sirko-and-user1687804)

Comment: @Sirko , I used this file_get_contents() .

Comment: @Sirko , After searched in php.net i have found this solution. To use this : file_get_contents() . 
And now see your suggestion here. 
Ya, that's work perfectly. Thanks Sirco :). 
will i add this solution in my post ?

Comment: @user1687804 You accepted this solution as an answer, so you don't have to do anything else, if the problem is solved for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`function

```
$variable=htmlentities("data");
```

Comment: or maybe `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: @think123 maybe, but `htmlentities` converts every character that has a html code. `htmlspecialchars` converts only a few, so you'll need to ask yourself when should I use which :)

Comment: IS it will work for all codes ? I mean <bg color >, <center > <marquess> all kinds of work in this method ?